# How to analyse a zip file forensically?

Tags: forensics, zip

I have a zip file and want to know as much as possible about it. Some information is obvious like creation date etc. But what kind of information could be found by a forensic analysis?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are exactly expecting which makes this question too broad. But, take a look at the [zip file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) to get a feeling for the kind of information you might get when analyzing a ZIP file.

Comment: What do you mean by 'forensic analysis'? The term is undefined. Are you asking what are all the ways to analyse a zip file to gain useful information?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Design

Comment: Perhaps you could mention some specific information you would like to gain from the analysis?

Comment: I could retrieve some information about the source file system. It states NTFS. So the system packing the zip runs probably under Windows. But how to determin the packer?

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'unzip' from fx. cygwin. `unzip -l Archive.zip` in a terminal/cmd.exe. While it will list dates of the files archive (CTIME and MTIME, perhaps) these are attributes that can be changed by anyone. The creation date of the zip-file is just the time at which it was downloaded/copied to your PC.